# How to mark mat-checkbox as checked in Angular 7

Tags: angular

I have used a mat-checkbox in my project. I tried to mark the mat-checkbox as checked by using [checked]="true"

```
<div *ngFor="let dwidgets of module.widgets">
  <mat-checkbox [formControl]="moduleswidgets.controls['widgets']"
   [checked]="(dwidgets['selected'] == '1')?true:false"
      class="example-margin" (change)="selectedWidgets($event,dwidgets['widgetsmst_pk'])">
   {{ dwidgets['wm_widgetname']}}
</mat-checkbox>
```

in the above code dwidgets['selected'] will return 1 and so it will set the checked event as true. But still checkbox was not checked.

Anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you're using a `formControl` the checked won't work.

you need to update the value of the control and it will update the checkbox accordingly.

but there's another issue here that you're adding the same control for all the checkboxes.

so .. you either remove the `formControl` and update the data yourself using the `change` method, or use [`[(ngModel)]`](https://angular.io/guide/forms#track-control-state-and-validity-with-ngmodel).

or you need to use [form arrays](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-2-defining-a-formarray-control)

please consider reading [forms in Angular](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview#introduction-to-forms-in-angular) to understand more.

Comment: can you give the example link for using formArrays

Comment: The link is in the "form arrays"
by the way :  https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-2-defining-a-formarray-control 
it includes examples and step by step tutorial.